# Java, Derby DB: Long startup time (10 minutes) after running for a month

Tags: java, database, startup, derby

I'm using **Derby** as my database of choice for my java application. The application basically stores a lot of information from different network resources while it’s running. It's basically just collecting information and stores it in the **Derby DB**.

In my daily working tasks there is no issue with the startup time of my application but recently I let it run for about a month which increased the size of the **Derby DB** to around **2.9 GB**.

After closing and opening my application I had to wait for about **10 minutes** until the application started up. I immediately closed and started the application again and this time it took only a few seconds, like normal. I was also very surprised to see that the size of my **Derby DB** decreased to **1.2 GB**.

My question: Is it possible that **Derby** optimizes the **DB** on every startup? Could this reason for the long load time and if so, is there anything I can do to avoid it?

Comment: Q: Are you familiar with the concept of a database "transaction log"?

Comment: No, looking it up right now!

Comment: After looking it up: This means that when I closed my application, the DB was in an inconsistent state and when starting it up again Derby tries to fix itself. So I may be able to fix it when I ensue that on closing the application the DB is consistent. Thank you!